# Use Selenium to download multiple URLs as PDFs

Tags: python, macos, selenium, pdf

I am trying to have Selenium download the URLs of a webpage as PDFs on Safari. So far, I have been able to open the URL, but I can't get Safari to download it. All the solutions I found so far were either for another browser, or they didn't work. Ideally I would like it to download all links of one page and then move on the next page.

At first I thought that clicking on each hyperlink and then downloading it was the way to go. But that would require switching windows each time, so then I tried to find a way to download it without having to click on it, but nothing worked.

I am quite new at programming so I am sure that I am missing something.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pdfkit


browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get(a_base_url)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("tb_LoginName")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("tb_Password")
submit = browser.find_element_by_id("btn_Login")
username.send_keys(username)
password.send_keys(password)
submit.click()

element=WebDriverWait(browser,   10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="maincolumn"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]/a[2]'))).click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
url=browser.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following approach:

1. Get [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) of the link you want to download via [WebElement.get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) function
2. Use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) or [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to retrieve the URL from step 1 without using the browser

Most probably you will also need to [get the browser Cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) via  [WebDriver.get_cookies](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookies) function and add them to [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header for your download request